# Implementation of Scheffe's adjustment in software

Tags: multiple-comparisons, sas, degrees-of-freedom

My understanding of Scheffé's adjustment for multiple comparisons is that it already adjusts for any possible contrast that one could make with the data, where the contrast coefficients sum to 0.  This means that if I used his adjustment, the CI will be the same whether I do 2 comparisons or 200 comparisons, whether I do pairwise comparisons or more complex comparisons, whether I've specified those comparisons before or after collecting data

However, in SAS, they implement Scheffé in a way that is dependent on the number of contrasts being performed.  More specifically, they link Scheffé to the rank of the contrast matrix.  In [Scheffé's paper](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/40/1-2/87/338564), he notes that the numerator DF is $(k - 1)$, where $k$ is the number of means estimated in the analysis.  Rather than using $(k - 1)$ as the numerator degrees of freedom, SAS uses the rank of the contrast matrix, which can be anything from $1$ to $k$.  If the rank of the contrast matrix happens to equal $(k - 1)$, as when doing all pairwise comparisons, then SAS's implementation matches Scheffé's paper.  Note that the rank could be $k$, which results in an even stricter adjustment than Scheffé suggests.

> Scheffé (1953, 1959) proposes another method to control the MEER for any set of contrasts or other linear hypotheses in the analysis of linear models, including pairwise comparisons, obtained with the SCHEFFE option. Two means are declared significantly different if $$|t_{ij}|≥\sqrt{DF\cdot F(\alpha; DF,\nu)}$$ where $F(\alpha; DF,\nu)$ is the $\alpha$-level critical value of an $F$ distribution with $DF$ numerator degrees of freedom and $\nu$ denominator degrees of freedom. The value of $DF$ is $k – 1$ for the MEANS statement, but in other statements the precise definition depends on context. For the LSMEANS statement, $DF$ is the rank of the contrast matrix $\textbf{L}$ for LS-means differences. In more general contexts—for example, the ESTIMATE or LSMESTIMATE statements in PROC GLIMMIX—DF is the rank of the contrast covariance matrix $\textbf{L}Cov(b)\textbf{L}'$ ([SAS Multiple Comparisons](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_glm_details29.htm)).

This produces a curious situation where Scheffé's adjustment changes depending on how you write the comparison in SAS.  If I write the same contrast in two separate statements, one by itself and one with a bunch of other (linearly independent) contrasts, I get two different Scheffé-adjusted CIs.  This seems to be at odds with the spirit of Scheffé's method.  If I'm getting different results depending on the rank, then at least some of those are not actually adjusting for all possible contrasts but instead all requested contrasts.

Am I misunderstanding Scheffé?  Or is there something I'm missing about it's application to real world data?

I tried to look up Scheffé in R, but I cannot find the statistical calculations, only explanation of syntax.  I am also in touch with SAS directly, asking them for a reference for changing $(k - 1)$ to the rank of $\textbf{L}$.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Michael